# Como escrever uma agenda em ordem alfabética de Nomes usando o OrderedDict do Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
Nomes = []
Telefones = []
Endereços = []
Emails = []
Agenda = {"Nome": Nomes,"Telefone":Telefones,"Endereço":Endereços,
          "Email": Emails}
entrada = ""

print("Bem-vindo a nossa Agenda!!!!!")
while entrada != "s":

    nome = input("Digite o nome: ")
    Nomes.append(nome)
    telefone = input("Digite o telefone: ")
    Telefones.append(telefone)
    endereço = input("Digite o endereço: ")
    Endereços.append(endereço)
    email = input("Digite o email: ")
    Emails.append(email)
    #print(Agenda)
    entrada = input("Deseja sair? ")
    print()
    if entrada.lower() == "s":
        ordenada = sorted(Agenda['Nome']) 
        for nome in ordenada:  
            print()
            print("Nome: ",Agenda['Nome'][Nomes.index(nome)])
            print("Telefone: ",Agenda['Telefone'][Nomes.index(nome)])
            print("Endereço: ",Agenda['Endereço'][Nomes.index(nome)])
            print("Email: ",Agenda['Email'][Nomes.index(nome)])
            print()
        break
```

O programa acima cria uma Agenda e imprime a, em ordem alfabética dos Nomes.
É possível fazer o mesmo programa usando o OrderedDict do Python?

Rascunho:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

Nomes = []
Telefones = []
Endereços = []
Emails = []
Agenda = OrderedDict()
Agenda['Nome'] = Nomes
```

Comment: Por quê separar todos os valores em listas diferentes? Não seria melhor criar um objeto para cada registro e criar uma lista de objetos?

Comment: @Anderson Carlos Woss: Sou bastante limitado em programação. Só consegui fazer assim! OrderedDict ajudaria em algo?

Answer (score 3):

Pelo visto, você lê alguns dados enquanto o usuário desejar e posteriormente exibe-os todos em ordem alfabética com base no nome. Será mais fácil de você criar um dicionário para cada registro e manter uma lista de dicionários. Algo assim:

```
from operator import itemgetter

agenda = []
print('Seja bem-vindo')
while True:
    nome = input('Nome: ')
    telefone = input('Telefone: ')
    email = input('E-mail: ')
    agenda.append(dict(nome=nome, telefone=telefone, email=email))
    entrada = input('Deseja sair? ')
    if entrada.lower() == 's':
        for pessoa in sorted(agenda, key=itemgetter('nome')):
            print('{p[nome]}, {p[telefone]}, {p[email]}'.format(p=pessoa))
        break
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/GenuineSophisticatedSequel)</sup>

Isso, inclusive, facilita outras operações com a lista, como, por exemplo buscar todos os registros das pessoas que possuem o nome começando com a letra A:

```
nomes_com_A = (pessoa for pessoa in agenda if pessoa['nome'].startswith('A'))

for pessoa in nomes_com_A:
    print('{p[nome]}, {p[telefone]}, {p[email]}'.format(p=pessoa))
```